# Serialise JSON color hex without quotes

Tags: c#, javascript, json, asp.net-mvc-4, serialization

So I am sending some values to a javascript array. Currently it is an array called data, that has two elements, value and color, for example:

```
var data = [{value:226,color:&quot;#FFFFF&quot;},{value:257,color:&quot;#FFFFF&quot;}];
```

The problem is that color should be color: #FFFFF WITHOUT the &quot surrounding. The C# is as follows:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class StatsValues
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public int value { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string color { get; set; }
}

var values = new List<StudentBrandsApp.Models.StatsValues>();
foreach (DataRow dr in statsDataTable.Rows)
{
    values.Add(new StudentBrandsApp.Models.StatsValues() { value = Convert.ToInt32(dr.ItemArray[1].ToString()), color = "#FFFFF" });
}

        var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        var writer = new JsonTextWriter(stringWriter);
        writer.QuoteName = false;
        serializer.Serialize(writer, values);
        writer.Close();
        var json = stringWriter.ToString();
        ViewData["json"] = json;
```

How do I serialise this so that color excludes the quotes and returns simply the hash value?

Comment: how you are stringify ... ? looks like u have to use HttpUtility.HtmlDecode to translate entities ...

Answer (score 0):

Please try your json string to below format:

```
{
  "array": [
  { 
     "value":226,
     "color":"#FFFFF"     
     },
   { 
     "value":226,
     "color":"#FFFFF"     
     }
  ]
}
```

or

```
var data = [{"value":226,"color":"#FFFFF"},{"value":257,"color":"#FFFFF"}];
```